# Using Hamachi to link domain controllers at multiple sites

Tags: active-directory, site-to-site-vpn, hamachi

I'm an IT guy at a start-up retail chain which uses AD (I've managed AD before but it was inside one physical location). Right now each site (HQ, shop1, shop2 and shop3) uses it's own AD domain. I'm looking to merge those into one so that the user accounts are shared and I don't have to recreate group policies manually.

All users, computers and printers are inside a special OU in each domain. For example the domain for shop 1 is **shop1.example.com** and all computers and users are inside **shop1** OU. This was done specially in preparation for the future merging.

So my plan was to use hamachi to link the domain controllers. The reason behind this is that the company doesn't want to spend money on hardware-based vpn solutions and some sites have very poor internet connection that I would prefer to keep as much as possible inside the physical networks.

Is this possible? If yes I how would I go about with the merger (got no clue about multiple DCs, replication, AD's sites, etc)? Also, what sort of problems can I expect to run into with this setup (I'm using DCs also as print, DNS (obviously) and file servers)?

Comment: If you are going to do something like that, I would look for a solution that doesn't have a history of IP squatting. As far as I know Hamachi still does IP squatting if you use IPv4, so I would avoid Hamachi unless you are already running your network as IPv6-only.

Comment: @kasperd Thanks for the warning. I haven't encountered that before, but I'll definitely not use Hamachi if that's the case. By the way, do you know if Hamachi gateway is guilty of that? I'm thinking to use that as an alternative

Comment: Hamachi as an alternative to Hamachi? I think you made a typo there. I have heard of another similar product responsible of squatting on IP addresses in the same way as Hamachi, but I don't recall the name.